# Django : Get subcategory respective category or reverse order

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am beginner in django. I want to get all subcategories in a respective category or reversible order.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_pt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null = True, blank = True, related_name = "subcategory")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True, default='1', help_text = "1= Active, 0= Inactive")

class Meta:
    db_table = 'news_category'

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.id
```

This is serializer class in serializer.py:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

I want serialized data as bellow:

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "data": [
   {
  "child": [],
  "id": 1,
  "name_en": "India",
  "name_pt": "Índia",
  "parent": null,
  "status": "1"
},
{
  "child": [  {
       "child":[],
       "id": 6,
       "name_en": "XYZ",
       "name_pt": "XYZ",
       "parent": 2,
       "status": "1"
      },
      {
      "child": [],
       "id": 7,
       "name_en": "ABC",
       "name_pt": "ABC",
       "parent": 2,
       "status": "1"
      }
   ],
  "id": 2,
  "name_en": "World",
  "name_pt": "mundo",
  "parent": null,
  "status": "1"
},
{
  "child": [],
  "id": 3,
  "name_en": "Cali",
  "name_pt": "cali",
  "parent": 3,
  "status": "1"
}
],
"error": 0
}
```

Above Json child has all data within parent data. I want this type of json Please help me.

https://gist.github.com/mhulse/1031882

Above link gives parent detail. But I also need child details or reverse order.

Comment: what do you mean by "reverse order"?

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33487576/3120525) answer